# disable images in XE5 mobile

Tags: delphi, mobile

When I disable a tImage in XE5 mobile the image is distorted or confused a little but does not behave as I would like. Using CreateFromBitmapAndMask does not do anything for me (maybe I do not know how to get this to work) but what I am wanting is for the image to become darker but still have the same image.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try lowering the Opacity of the image to see if that gives the effect you are after.

Comment: I did try that. The result was much the same as disabling. Eventually I went for a second set of images with the desired coloring.